# Pending from incomplete transaction

Tags: payment-processor

Registrants have status recorded as  Pending from incomplete transaction
even after PayPal has collected fee and confirmed payment

I have been over the PayPal processor setup multiple times and believe I have followed the text.

I have created an event and assigned the PayPal processor to it.
When I do a  registration civicrm accepts the registration and presents me to the PayPal site. the payment is made , charging the registrant and completing the payment to my merchant account, PayPal returns me to the registration page with the message "Your registration payment has been submitted to test *( test is the name of the fees for this event)* for processing. Please print this page for your records."
 PayPal merchant account sends out a notice to both my PayPal merchant email and the registrant email confirming the transaction.

when I look in the event registration list to view the registrants, there are no attendees paid. 
Only when I look in Pending from incomplete transaction do I find the listing with the pending notice attached.

CiviCRM version:     4.6
CMS version:     wordpress 4.3.1
MySQL version:     5.5.42
PHP version:     4.0.10.7

Comment: I reckon you will need to give a little more information for people to be able to provide a decent answer? Unfortunately I have no experience with PayPal so I can not help you :-(

Comment: Solution to problem - working on old WP install (4years old) -  removed the htaccess file in the wp-content folder which made it impossible for outside sources to access php code. works now !!!

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue on your Joomla/Civi sites? I have just started experiencing the same problem on my site after one of the recent updates. I am running Joomla 3.5.1 with Civi 4.7.7 Your feedback will be greatly appreciated. Cheers,
Adri

Comment: Since you found the solution - please add an answer (not a comment) and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check PayPal IPN is configured properly or not.

Comment: IPN appears to be correct, Have a paypal support request

Comment: Should  my site be listed with paypal as http or https? documentation just says http://www.example.com, have tried both

Comment: If you have enabled SSL for civicrm then you nees to use https otherwise http.

Comment: Paypal is sending IPN to the website link  that generates a page not found

Comment: the error log for the site records:  [13-Dec-2015 13:48:44 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'status timestamp <= 1355406524 and id not in (select redirect_id from oxhhm_wbz4' at line 1 for query select id from oxhhm_wbz404_redirects where status = 2 status timestamp <= 1355406524 and id not in (select redirect_id from oxhhm_wbz404_logs) made by do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array, wbz404_cleaningCron

Comment: the link looks looks this........../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php?reset=1&contactID=2&contributionID=12&module=event&eventID=1&participantID=12

Comment: Problem fixed- folder was set to not writable. changed access and it works

Comment: which folder was not set to writable? @Rob